# JSQLParser skip UDF token evaluation

Tags: jsqlparser

Consider the following code

```java
        String sql ="SELECT NAME, ADDRESS, COL1 FROM USER WHERE SSN IN ('11111111111111', '22222222222222') and abcd_exists(fn,v -> isNotNull(v));";
        Select select = (Select) CCJSqlParserUtil.parse(sql);
```

Now, since the function `abcd_exists` is not recognized, the parse would throw an exception.

Is there a way to bypass the validation in JSQLParser? I would want to "tell" not validate `abcd_exists(fn,v -> isNotNull(v))` part of the sql statement.